# How to make Carousel slider of Twitter Bootstrap Dynamic in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have using this piece of code ( http://pastie.org/private/wg75kjtgq0xcetudzpxlq )  for making the carousel slider from twitter bootstrap dynamic in `WordPress`.This code works fine until the loop fetches two post with images from the given category. but when there is only one post with image in given category . This loop doesn't work correctly ( Shows error after sliding the first image. How can I solve this problem ?

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, on l.29 `has_post_thumbnail` misses parentheses:

`has_post_thumbnail()`

Second, you don't need to instantiate a new wp query for each individual item, set `posts_per_page` to e.g. 2 and use a counter to add the active class to the first item, see example [here](https://github.com/diggy/wp-bootstrap-carousel/blob/master/wp-bootstrap-carousel.php#L142)